# React leaflet How to have all markers with a specific icons but the one active with a different icon

Tags: reactjs, dictionary, leaflet, marker, react-leaflet

So I am trying to have an active marker that is different from the rest of the non active marker.

So basically I want something like this.

[image]

To display all of the icon I am using the following.

that is displayed inside the map

```
{parkdata.features.map(park =>(
          <Marker key = {park.properties.PARK_ID} position={[
            park.geometry.coordinates[1], 
            park.geometry.coordinates[0]
           
          ]}
          onClick={()=>{this.selected(park);
```

The selected function that was intended to be used to change the active icon. But it does not seem to be doing anything

```
 selected(park){
    return(
    <Marker key = {park.properties.PARK_ID} position={[
      park.geometry.coordinates[1], 
      park.geometry.coordinates[0]
     
    ]}
    icon= {active}
    />
    )
  }
```

UPDATE:
This is what I have now.

[image]

SO when I click on one of the markers I want to change to a different icon. For now, it just does not do anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following example demonstrates how to create a markers and update icon property on marker click:

```
function createIcon(url) {
  return new L.Icon({
    iconUrl: url,
  });
}

function MapExample(props) {
  const [selectedIndex, setSelectedIndex] = useState(-1);

  function handleClick(e) {
    setSelectedIndex(e.target.options.index) //get index via custom marker property
  }

  function getMarkerIcon(index) {
    if(index === selectedIndex)
          return createIcon("/bigcity_red.png");
    return createIcon("/bigcity_green.png");
  }

  return (
    <Map center={props.center} zoom={props.zoom}>
      <TileLayer
        url="https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"
        attribution='&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
      />
      {props.data.map((item, index) => (
        <Marker
          key={index}
          index={index}
          position={item.position}
          icon={getMarkerIcon(index)}
          onclick={handleClick}
        />
      ))}
    </Map>
  );
}
```

Notes:

- `icon` property for Marker component expects the value of [`L.Icon` type](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.6.0.html#icon)
- `selectedIndex` state is used to keep track of selected Marker (index)

[Here is a demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-xqvbdp) for your reference